# better wordpress minify problem

Tags: optimization

i am using [better wordpress minify](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-plugins/bwp-minify/) plugin 
but it breaks site due to one of css file

```
http://www.mydomain.net/?mcsf_action=main_css&#038;ver=3.1.1
```

i would like to add it into exception list so that it ignores it

here's screen-shot for admin panel 
http://bayimg.com/jaHFdAaDj

it says **Type in one script handle (NOT filename) per line**

so what should be the script handle in this case thanks

it looks like this

`http://www.domain.net/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=?mcsf_action=main_css&ver=1.2.2,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/themes/ishop/ishop.css,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/themes/compatibility.css,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/js/product_rater.css,index.php?wpsc_user_dynamic_css=true&category=5,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/js/thickbox.css`

firephp shows Minify: GET param 'f' invalid (see MinApp.php line 63)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of that plugin. I think you should post such question on WP.org's support forum or on my website so I can get to you faster. If not for the pingback from this site I wouldn't know you are asking this :).

About your issue, how did you enqueue that file? How does your minify URL look like when my plugin is enabled?

Edit: And here is the answer: http://betterwp.net/163-bwp-minify-released/comment-page-1/#comment-93

Comment: this should really be a comment and not an answer

Comment: its looks like this 'http://www.mydomain.net/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=?mcsf_action=main_css&ver=1.2.2,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/themes/ishop/ishop.css,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/themes/compatibility.css,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/js/product_rater.css,index.php?wpsc_user_dynamic_css=true&category=5,wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/js/thickbox.css

Comment: @Bainternet is it considered an answer now? Sorry I'm not used to this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just make sure you are *not* queuing the scripts or styles with a *double slash*, like doing `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."/css/style.css"`, this makes the URL of the style like `"http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN//css/style.css"` and wp-minify fails to minify this URL.